# How to display blue status bar, if a action running in background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, statusbar, screensharing

I have installed refector 2 app in iPhone. While recoding iphone screen, the status bar colour has been changed to blue.

check below screen shot. Any idea how they did this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. The OS does this for you, to let the user know that some app is doing actions in background (recording screen, using microphone, using hotspot, etc.). If your app does something like this in background the statusbar will be displayed accordingly.

Comment: i have tried with background audio recoding and location updates. Application working good. But i didn't get blue status bar.

Comment: The color is different for each such task and it cannot be changed. Red for audio, blue for location and there are some others.

Comment: The app has to be in background and actively use one of those services.