# Change text in status bar while app in background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, statusbar

I want to change the text of red bar shown below, how do I do it? I see it when my swift app is currently using the microphone and is in the background.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot change it yourself.**

> This is a system level event that occurs when your app is running in
>   background stage and using services like location, audio, etc. This
>   [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) discusses about the types of background services an app can
>   use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194933/how-to-display-blue-status-bar-if-a-action-running-in-background has already discussed it.

Comment: I understand that I can't change the color but I don't see where it says that I can't change the text

Comment: Text is picked up by the system on the basis of the app name and the type of background service your app uses. It is not customisable.